# JSF2 Can't reach SessionScoped bean from ViewScoped as ManagedProperty

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a strange problem. Afaik I can inject a SessionScoped bean into a viewscoped, because its broader, than the other. Here is my code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProjectBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{projectCurrentBean}")
private ProjectCurrentBean currentBean;

public void setCurrentBean(ProjectCurrentBean currentBean) {
    this.currentBean = currentBean;
}     

@ManagedProperty(value="#{userCredentialsBean}")
private UserCredentialsBean activeUser;

public void setActiveUser(UserCredentialsBean activeUser) {
    this.activeUser = activeUser;
}
```

The 2 managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectCurrentBean implements Serializable  {
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserCredentialsBean  implements Serializable {
```

It works fine with the UserCredentialsBean, but when I put the ProjectCurrentBean it fails:

```
Unable to create managed bean projectBean. The following problems were found: - The scope of the object referenced by expression #{projectCurrentBean}, request, is shorter   than the referring managed beans (projectBean) scope of view
```

why? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've not declared the bean using `@SessionScoped` from [`javax.faces.bean` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/package-summary.html), but instead from [`javax.enterprise.context` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/package-summary.html). This don't work in combination with `@ManagedBean` from `javax.faces.bean` package. The bean will then default to the request scope and behave like [`@RequestScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html).

Fix your imports.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectCurrentBean implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Be careful with IDE autocomplete.